# Searching LONG datatype in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am looking for a way to search columns with a LONG datatype.

I know those are deprecated (and I've always hated working with them...), but for some reason Oracle themselves continue to use them in their own tables and views...

Basically I want to build a query on `SYS.USER_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS` with the WHERE-clause filtering a specific `HIGH_VALUE`.

HIGH_VALUE is of the LONG datatype and the only way I know to filter those things, is by using the undocumented function `dbms_metadata_util.long2varchar`

When executing a query with this function however, the returned value is NULL.

```
select sys.dbms_metadata_util.long2varchar(2000,'SYS.USER_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS','HIGH_VALUE', rowid) from USER_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS;
```

This is most likely because `USER_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS` is not actually a table, but a view. And views don't have rowids...

However, it seems to be a strange kind of view, as its definition does not show any underlying base table. Instead it just creates a synonym on itself.

So, to my actual question(s): Is there any other way to query LONG? Does anybody know the "base table" of `USER_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, data type `LONG` in Oracle System-Views is a pain. When I have to use such values I use this one:

```
DECLARE
    high_value INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR aPart IN (SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS) LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT high_value;

        SELECT ...
        WHERE ... = high_value;

    end loop;

END;
```

Note, in this example `HIGH_VALUE` is an integer value. However, it can be anything else (e.g. a TIMESTAMP), consider this in your procedure. For example like this:

```
FUNCTION IntervalType(tableName IN VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

    EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE, -6550);

    ds INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;
    ym INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH;
    str VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN

    SELECT INTERVAL
    INTO str 
    FROM USER_PART_TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = tableName;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||str||'; END;' USING OUT ym;
    RETURN 'YEAR TO MONTH Interval of '||ym;

EXCEPTION 
    WHEN EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||str||'; END;' USING OUT ds;
        RETURN 'DAY TO SECOND Interval of '||ds;

END IntervalType;
```

Comment: Thanks, will add this to my code snippet collection :)

Answer (score 2):

If you query `ALL_VIEWS` or `DBA_VIEWS`, you will find the definition of the view  `USER_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS`

```
SELECT TEXT
  FROM all_views
 WHERE view_name = 'USER_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS';
```

You will see that the `HIGH_VALUE` comes from `hiboundval` column of `sys.tabsubpart$`.

There is one other way we use to extract the `HIGH_VALUE` . You may use `SUBSTR()` to extract the exact values from the extracted `HIGH_VALUE`.

```
DECLARE
v_high_value VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (
          DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXMLTYPE (
                'SELECT high_value                                                                    
FROM all_tab_partitions                                                                   
WHERE partition_name='''
             || YOUR_PARTITION_NAME
             || '''                                                                     
AND table_owner='''
             || YOUR_TABLE_OWNER
             || '''                                                                     
AND table_name='''
             || YOUR_TABLE
             || ''''),
          'ROWSET/ROW/HIGH_VALUE') INTO v_high_value
  FROM DUAL;

END;
/
```

You may refer [Ask TOM](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9522731800346411985)  article here

Comment: Is this really a solution? Because table `sys.tabsubpart$` still contains `LONG` column, so you actual problem is just shifted from view `USER_TAB_SUBPARTITIONS` to table `sys.tabsubpart$`.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : I had not completed my answer; I was about to include part of some code, somewhat similar to yours to fetch the long value, but just had saved the answer. I just came back and saw it has already been accepted. Anyway your answer explains it all well and deserves to be the right answer.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I changed the "accepted" answer to yours, as it does provide a lot more detail and is more generalized. I was initially able to solve my problem with the answer from @KaushikNayak, because he provided me with `hiboundval`and `sys.tabsubpart$`, which allowed me to adapt my implementation of `sys.dbms_metadata_util.long2varchar` to return the desired result. Anyway, thank you both for your help!